# Valgrind sees delete in the line that says new

Tags: c++, valgrind, poco-libraries

When I was checking my application for memory leaks I came across a very peculiar behavior of valgrind. As far I understand he sees the following code

```
virtual ServiceHandler* createServiceHandler(StreamSocket& socket)
    /// Create and initialize a new ServiceHandler instance.
    ///
    /// Subclasses can override this method.
{
    return new ServiceHandler(socket, *_pReactor);
}
```

as a place where I both allocate and free memory. This code is part of POCO library and it can be found [here](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/include/Poco/Net/SocketAcceptor.h). Below is an example of log from valgrind saying that the provided return statement results in both new and delete.

```
Invalid read of size 8
==9764==    at 0x1C63DC: Poco::Net::Socket::operator!=(Poco::Net::Socket const&) const (Socket.h:340)
==9764==    by 0x1C2A5C: SocketHandler::onReadableNotification(Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::ReadableNotification> const&) (SocketHandler.cpp:67)
==9764==    by 0x1CA0DF: Poco::NObserver<SocketHandler, Poco::Net::ReadableNotification>::notify(Poco::Notification*) const (NObserver.h:88)
==9764==    by 0x5C04077: Poco::NotificationCenter::postNotification(Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Notification>) (NotificationCenter.cpp:78)
==9764==    by 0x579F422: Poco::Net::SocketNotifier::dispatch(Poco::Net::SocketNotification*) (SocketNotifier.cpp:80)
==9764==    by 0x579C0DC: Poco::Net::SocketReactor::dispatch(Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::SocketNotifier>&, Poco::Net::SocketNotification*) (SocketReactor.cpp:282)
==9764==    by 0x579BEE1: Poco::Net::SocketReactor::dispatch(Poco::Net::Socket const&, Poco::Net::SocketNotification*) (SocketReactor.cpp:258)
==9764==    by 0x579B5F4: Poco::Net::SocketReactor::run() (SocketReactor.cpp:114)
==9764==    by 0x5C50406: Poco::(anonymous namespace)::RunnableHolder::run() (Thread.cpp:57)
==9764==    by 0x5C500E0: Poco::ThreadImpl::runnableEntry(void*) (Thread_POSIX.cpp:349)
==9764==    by 0x6D20493: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==9764==    by 0x78BBAFE: clone (clone.S:97)
==9764==  Address 0x10c8f908 is 40 bytes inside a block of size 352 free'd
==9764==    at 0x4C2D2DB: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:576)
==9764==    --> by 0x19D1CD: Poco::Net::SocketAcceptor<SocketHandler>::createServiceHandler(Poco::Net::StreamSocket&) (SocketAcceptor.h:166) 
==9764==    by 0x19B3E3: Poco::Net::SocketAcceptor<SocketHandler>::onAccept(Poco::Net::ReadableNotification*) (SocketAcceptor.h:157)
==9764==    by 0x1A1385: Poco::Observer<Poco::Net::SocketAcceptor<SocketHandler>, Poco::Net::ReadableNotification>::notify(Poco::Notification*) const (Observer.h:86)
==9764==    by 0x5C04077: Poco::NotificationCenter::postNotification(Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Notification>) (NotificationCenter.cpp:78)
==9764==    by 0x579F422: Poco::Net::SocketNotifier::dispatch(Poco::Net::SocketNotification*) (SocketNotifier.cpp:80)
==9764==    by 0x579C0DC: Poco::Net::SocketReactor::dispatch(Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::SocketNotifier>&, Poco::Net::SocketNotification*) (SocketReactor.cpp:282)
==9764==    by 0x579BEE1: Poco::Net::SocketReactor::dispatch(Poco::Net::Socket const&, Poco::Net::SocketNotification*) (SocketReactor.cpp:258)
==9764==    by 0x579B5F4: Poco::Net::SocketReactor::run() (SocketReactor.cpp:114)
==9764==    by 0x5C50406: Poco::(anonymous namespace)::RunnableHolder::run() (Thread.cpp:57)
==9764==    by 0x5C500E0: Poco::ThreadImpl::runnableEntry(void*) (Thread_POSIX.cpp:349)
==9764==    by 0x6D20493: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==9764==  Block was alloc'd at
==9764==    at 0x4C2C21F: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==9764==    --> by 0x19D19E: Poco::Net::SocketAcceptor<SocketHandler>::createServiceHandler(Poco::Net::StreamSocket&) (SocketAcceptor.h:166)
==9764==    by 0x19B3E3: Poco::Net::SocketAcceptor<SocketHandler>::onAccept(Poco::Net::ReadableNotification*) (SocketAcceptor.h:157)
==9764==    by 0x1A1385: Poco::Observer<Poco::Net::SocketAcceptor<SocketHandler>, Poco::Net::ReadableNotification>::notify(Poco::Notification*) const (Observer.h:86)
==9764==    by 0x5C04077: Poco::NotificationCenter::postNotification(Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Notification>) (NotificationCenter.cpp:78)
==9764==    by 0x579F422: Poco::Net::SocketNotifier::dispatch(Poco::Net::SocketNotification*) (SocketNotifier.cpp:80)
==9764==    by 0x579C0DC: Poco::Net::SocketReactor::dispatch(Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::SocketNotifier>&, Poco::Net::SocketNotification*) (SocketReactor.cpp:282)
==9764==    by 0x579BEE1: Poco::Net::SocketReactor::dispatch(Poco::Net::Socket const&, Poco::Net::SocketNotification*) (SocketReactor.cpp:258)
==9764==    by 0x579B5F4: Poco::Net::SocketReactor::run() (SocketReactor.cpp:114)
==9764==    by 0x5C50406: Poco::(anonymous namespace)::RunnableHolder::run() (Thread.cpp:57)
==9764==    by 0x5C500E0: Poco::ThreadImpl::runnableEntry(void*) (Thread_POSIX.cpp:349)
==9764==    by 0x6D20493: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
```

I added `-->` to the interesting part.

Once this happens I observe more of similar logs as the object appears not to be allocated. The app works correctly for some time before I see this error and it is the first one to happen. I think that this error may occur when the socket acts not nice.

I valgrind the app using the following command

```
valgrind --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0 app
```

and use gdb to further inspect the code.

My question are:

- Why does the valgrind tell me the provided code invokes both new and delete?
- Is this behavior caused by this code locally or should I look for the problem somewhere else?

@edit

ctor

```
SocketHandler::SocketHandler(StreamSocket &socket, SocketReactor &reactor) :
    _socket(socket) /* copy */, _reactor(reactor) /* reference */ {

    _socket.setBlocking(false);

    _reactor.addEventHandler(_socket, NObserver<SocketHandler, ReadableNotification>(*this,
                                                                                 &SocketHandler::onReadableNotification));
    _reactor.addEventHandler(_socket,
                         NObserver<SocketHandler, ErrorNotification>(*this, &SocketHandler::onErrorNotification));
    _reactor.addEventHandler(_socket, NObserver<SocketHandler, ShutdownNotification>(*this,
                                                                                 &SocketHandler::onShutdownNotification));

    _addr = _socket.peerAddress().toString();
}
```

Comment: The ctor news and then deletes a temp object instance?

Comment: There are no manual allocations in ctor. I only register the callbacks. I will soon attach the code of ctor. I also think that if such thing were to happen the stack trace would have been longer

Comment: Concerning the temp. instance which could be deleted, I suspect `*_pReactor`. To prove (or disprove) this, two additional things would be necessary to know: 1st.: type of `_pReactor`, 2nd.: signature of `ServiceHandler::ServiceHandler()`.

Comment: Another reason might be that `ServiceHandler::ServiceHandler()` should have 1st arg. of type `StreamSocket&` but (due to typo) the `&` might be missing.

Comment: Reactor lives approximately as long as the whole application. If the reactor ceased to exists it means that the application had started to shutdown, but the application still appears to work correctly after the error. I edited the question to include ctor.

Comment: The `new` expression will first call `operator new` to allocate memory and then execute the constructor. If construction fails (with an exception) `operator delete` will be called to release the allocated memory, so it doesn't leak.

Comment: @bo This is probably correct I will check it out when I get the chance. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Bo Persson in comments, the delete was caused by an unhandled exception in the constructor. After catching relevant exceptions in the ctor, and moving the expression that was throwing exceptions before the lines responsible for registering the event handlers

```
SocketHandler::SocketHandler(Poco::Net::StreamSocket &socket, SocketReactor &reactor) :
        _socket(socket), _reactor(reactor) {
    try {
        _socket.setBlocking(false);
        _addr = _socket.peerAddress().toString();

        _reactor.addEventHandler(_socket, NObserver<SocketHandler, ReadableNotification>(*this,
                                                                                         &SocketHandler::onReadableNotification));
        _reactor.addEventHandler(_socket,
                                 NObserver<SocketHandler, ErrorNotification>(*this,
                                                                             &SocketHandler::onErrorNotification));
        _reactor.addEventHandler(_socket, NObserver<SocketHandler, ShutdownNotification>(*this,
                                                                                         &SocketHandler::onShutdownNotification));
    } catch (Exception& e) {
        // Handle POCO exception
    } catch (...) {
        // Handle ellipsis
    }
}
```

the invalid memory access is no more. The exception is thrown by `_socket.peerAddress()` when trying to get an address of a socket that is no longer connected. At first I thought that any exception in the ctor would cause the app to swiftly crash but in the `Poco::Net::SocketReactor` every unhandled exception is passed to an `ErrorHandler`. That is why the application continued to work even after throwing unhandled exceptions. The referred code can be found [here](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/src/SocketReactor.cpp):126.

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind message does not indicate that you have a new and a delete at the same line of code.

The valgrind error message contains 3 stack traces.

The first stack trace is where the error is detected. This error consists in reading a piece of memory that was freed.

Valgrind then tries to give you more information about this piece of memory.
For this, it shows you 2 additional stack traces:

The second stack trace indicates where this piece of memory was freed.
The third stack trace indicates where this piece of memory was allocated.

Explained in other words: your code has first allocated a piece of memory (at 
stack trace nr 3). Your code has then freed this piece of memory (at stack trace nr 2).
And then your code wrongly accesses this piece of memory (at stack trace nr 1).

So, this all looks like you have a real bug : you are using a dangling pointer, pointing at released memory.

You might have to look at the generated code to see exactly which calls to new/delete are generated for the createServiceHandler call.
Clearly, there are 2 different instructions (0x19D1CD and 0x19D19E) in the 'new' and 'delete' stack traces.

Comment: except trace nr 2 doesnt free anything - unless its a side effect of a malloc, which would be odd

Comment: According to Valgrind, there is a call to a delete at instruction 0x19D1CD. Of course, valgrind can have a bug (I have never seen such a bug of wrong calls, but valgrind unwinder sometimes had bugs). The best is to disassemble the function that contains 0x19D19E and 0x19D1CD, and see effectively what calls are there.

Comment: I am afraid that I am not knowledgeable enough to get any useful conclusions from disassembly in any reasonable amount of time. The correct answer is probably the one given in the comment to question. aka the delete is caused by an uncaught exception.